# Android: Home, Menu, Back, and Search Button don't work

Tags: android

Using the Gingerbread source, I compiled the code and loaded the ROM onto my Nexus One, but after starting the phone, the Home, Menu, Back, and Search buttons don't work anymore. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: You are doing something extremely advanced in building your own Android ROM - you are better off asking this question in places like http://forum.xda-developers.com where like-minded people hang out.

Comment: I think this may be related to the way in which handset manufacturers configure android for their own platform. Try looking for any Nexus One specific source files on the Android source site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was building the wrong version for my phone. I was building and loading a generic version instead of the HTC Passion version.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, when just installing CM7 after playing around with the N1 Honeycomb port. I had to do a wipe, the install CM6, made sure that worked fine, then wipe and install CM7... Now everything works fine again